# Want to see rendered HTML with same formatting as TinyMCE Codesample Plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, formatting, tinymce, nodes

Here is a picture of my edit page where TinyMCE is included: 
[In my edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuKiz.png)

When rendered outside of TinyMCE the codesample formatting is not showing [view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN6Sb.png). I want to have the same formatting when rendering the content as I see in TinyMCE when using the codesample plugin.

Here is the code I am using to invoke TinyMCE (4.3.2) .

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 200,
  language: 'bn_BD',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code codesample fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function(e) {
          if(e.state) {
              $('header').hide();
          }
          else {
              $('header').show();
          }
      });
  },
  toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | codesample link image media | forecolor backcolor',
  image_advtab: true,
  imagetools_cors_hosts: ['celica.muktosoft.com'],
  templates: [
    { title: 'Lesson Template', content: 'Test 1' }
  ],
  file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    if(type=='image') {
        document.getElementById("fileupload_field_id").value = field_name;
        document.getElementById("fileupload").value = "";
        document.getElementById("fileupload").click();
    }
  },
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include the CSS (and JavaScript) file from [prism.js download page](http://prismjs.com/download.html) (select the languages you need!) on your "view page".

When entering a code snippet in TinyMCE using Codesample plugin, remember to select the corresponding language at the top of the window of Codesample... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The key to resolving this is knowing that TinyMCE relies on Prism.js for the syntax highlighting capability.  If you want to extract the content from TinyMCE and have it appear elsewhere you need to...

**Step 1:**

Include Prism.js and prism.css in your page - these can be downloaded from the Prism web site.

**Step 2:**

Use TinyMCE's APIs to extract the content from the editor. For example:

```
var htmlToLoad = tinyMCE.get('area3').getContent();
```

**Step 3:**

Place the content into an HTML block element:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = htmlToLoad;
```

**Step 4:**

Run Prism's highlight function: `Prism.highlightAll();`

This triggers Prism to re-evaluate the DOM for things that it should highlight - it won't do this automatically.

Comment: I have included prism.css and prism.js in my page but syntext highlighting isnot showing for C code as well java , ruby , c# , c++ , python etc. Interesting point is that syntext highlighting is showing perfectly for javascript , css , HTML code . what to do :(

Comment: Go to Prism.js and make sure you select all of those languages for the build of Prism.js that you are using includes the languages you need.

Comment: Thank you sir , only php is not showing proper highlighting yet

Comment: Prism's default JS/CSS does not include PHP ... you have to build a custom Prism JS/CSS that includes PHP as a language.  This is done on the Prism.js web site.

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I save all the content to the backend and then retrieve it back it does not show code highlighting. When I save temporary as `innerHtml` on a `div#result` it shows but not when I save it and view this content on other page. Any idea towards that. Thanks